# DataGridView prepopulated with empty rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my Windows forms I use DataGridViews a lot. Is there a way that DataGridView is prepopulated with empty rows and not with their default look, which is like this:

[image]

I know that I can do it by simply inserting empty rows before DataGridView loads, but this solution is not practical. Is there any property or something which can change default look?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DataGridViewRowCollection.Add` method like this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(100);//pre-add 100 empty rows
```

Comment: I know for that method. Is there anything else, probably some setting in designer, so this can be pre-setted? Or do I need completely different control? I think about that more and more. Is DataGridView the only control to show rows of data in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties you have a property called "AllowUserstoAddRows" which you can enable it to true and you get the desired result.

Cheers.